# Java Final Project Animal Monitoring System

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Alright so I've built this code for my final project in this Java class. The instructions given are as follows:

> Option 2: Monitoring System
>   As a zookeeper, it is important to know the activities of the animals in your care and to monitor their living habitats. Create a monitoring system that does all of the following:
>
> Asks a user if they want to monitor an animal, monitor a habitat, or exit
>   Displays a list of animal/habitat options (based on the previous selection) as read from either the animals or habitats file
>
> Asks the user to enter one of the options
>
> - Displays the monitoring information by finding the appropriate section in the file
> - Separates sections by the category and selection (such as “Animal - Lion” or “Habitat -Penguin”)
> - Uses a dialog box to alert the zookeeper if the monitor detects something out of the normal range (These will be denoted in the files by a new line
>     starting with *****. Do not display the asterisks in the dialog.)
> - Allows a user to return to the original options

The code I've developed is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public class Final {


static final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String args[]) {

    System.out.println("Menu:");

    System.out.println("Monitor Animal");

    System.out.println("Monitor Habitat");

    System.out.println("Exit");



Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);

String userInput1 = input1.nextLine();



    if (userInput1.equals("Monitor Animal")); {

        System.out.println("Details on lions");

        System.out.println("Details on tigars");

        System.out.println("Details on bears");

        System.out.println("Details on giraffes");

        System.out.println("Exit");



        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userInput2 = input2.nextLine();



        switch(userInput2) {

            case 1: userInput2 = "Details on lions";

                System.out.println("Animal - Lion");

                System.out.println("Name: Leo");

                System.out.println("Age: 5");

                System.out.println("Health concerns: Cut on left front paw");

                System.out.println("Feeding schedule: Twice daily");

                break;



            case 2: userInput2 = "Details on tigers";

                System.out.println("Animal - Tigar");

                System.out.println("Name: Maj");

                System.out.println("Health concerns: None");

                System.out.println("Feeding schedule: 3x daily");

                break;



            case 3: userInput2 = "Details on bears";

                System.out.println("Animal - Bear");

                System.out.println("Name: Baloo");

                System.out.println("Age: 1");

                System.out.println("Health concerns: None");

                System.out.println("Feeding schedule: None on record");

                break;



            case 4: userInput2 = "Details on giraffes";

                System.out.println("Animal - Giraffe");

                System.out.println("Name: Spots");

                System.out.println("Age: 12");

                System.out.println("Health concerns: None");

                System.out.println("Feeding schedule: Grazing");

                break;



            case 5: userInput2 = "Exit";

                break;



            default: userInput2 = System.out.println("Error: Invalid Animal");

                break;

            }



    if (userInput1.equals("Monitor Habitat")); {

        System.out.println("Details on penguin habitat");

        System.out.println("Details on bird house");

        System.out.println("Details on aquarium");

        System.out.println("Exit");



        Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userInput3 = input3.nextLine();



        switch(userInput3) {



            case 1: userInput3 = "Details on penguin habitat";

                System.out.println("Habitat - Penguin");

                System.out.println("Temperature: Freezing");

                System.out.println("Food source: Fish in water running low");

                System.out.println("Cleanliness: Passed");

                break;



            case 2: userInput3 = "Details on bird house";

                System.out.println("Habitat - Bird");

                System.out.println("Temperature: Moderate");

                System.out.println("Food source: Natural from environment");

                System.out.println("Cleanliness: Passed");

                break;



            case 3: userInput3 = "Details on aquarium";

                System.out.println("Habitat - Aquarium");

                System.out.println("Temperature: Varies with output temperature");

                System.out.println("Food source: Added daily");

                System.out.println("Cleanliness: Needs cleaning from algae");

                break;



            case 4: userInput3 = "Exit";

                break;



            default: System.out.println("Error: Invalid Habitat");

                break;
    }



    if (userInput1.equals("Exit")); {

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");


    }

  }
}
```

It won't compile and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Is there a better way to do this? I've been trying for a day and a half and now it's due in about 3 hours. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the format of **if-else** statement,you are doing is wrong. do not provide the semicolon after the expression. it should be in the form

```
 if(expression){
 //statement

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the switch statement, you are comparing int with a string. So, you should compare a String with a String. For example in your code:

```
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput2 = input2.nextLine();
    switch(userInput2) {

        case "Details on lions":
            System.out.println("Animal - Lion");
            System.out.println("Name: Leo");
            System.out.println("Age: 5");
            System.out.println("Health concerns: Cut on left front paw");
            System.out.println("Feeding schedule: Twice daily");
            break;
```

Comment: I made the edits and took out the commas on my if statements and it gives me an error.

"/Final.java:212: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
1 error"

Comment: You are getting this error because of the number of brackets that you open in the if statement is not equal to the number you close. I recommend, to put an additional close bracket after the switch statement. Also, to change the second if statement if (userInput1.equals("Monitor Habitat")) for an else if statement and to change the last if statement for an else. To create a complete execution flow.

Answer (score 0):

no semicolon on if(example);

just type

```
if(){ 
} // simple as that.
```

Your switch case also has a problem. Needs to be

```
 case 'Details on penguin habitat':
 break;

 case 'Details on bird house':
 break
```